# Is it possible to read-only Twitter in Emacs?

Tags: twitter

I'd like to follow some accounts on Twitter, but would prefer not to open an account with them - I want to use Twitter read-only.  What I'd like is define a list of accounts I want to read, and have a "check for new tweets" functionality.

Is this possible in Emacs? What would I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried any of the [twitter options on the wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Twitter)?

Comment: I run a server inside emacs that reads my twitter feed and generates "bookmarks" in org mode (along with my RSS feeds). It uses ttytter and then parses the output of it. Not sure how to do that without an account though.